# how to show database results based on name of form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a property website and have developed the pages that setup the insert query to input the data required. I can show the data based on the id and other information as per the url. On the main page I have a form that I need to show results for.

Database type - innodb

relevant Database structure

```
Table | Fields
property | id, name, description, developer_id,agent_id,area_id, price, bed, bath, type_id
agent |id,agent
developer |id, developer
area | id, city_id, area
city | id, country_id, city
country | id, country
type | id, type
```

The databases have been left joined so property table fields have a relationship with their counterpart as per field_id to table.id using the PHPMyAdmin relationship manager

I can use `_isset` and `_get` to show results based on the url as this is how I am showing another page which lists the currently selected property, but for this form, there will be no particular url definition as it will be displayed on many different types of pages.

on a side note, im using jqtransform so some elements are pseudo css and not the actual buttons, inputs.

A form example with variables

```
 <?php

require 'connect.php';
$title="Property";


$table="property";
$table2="developer";
$table3="agent";
$table4="area";
$table7="type";

$col1="name";
$col2="developer";
$col3="agent";
$col4="area";
$col5="size";
$col6="furnished";
$col7="type";
$col8="finished";
$col9="delivery";
$col10="price";
$col11="bed";
$col12="bath";
$col13="pool";
$col14="featured";
$col15="img";
$col16="imgname";



$title2="Developer";
$title3="Agent";
$title4="Area";
$title5="Size";
$title6="Furnished?";
$title7="Type of Property";
$title8="Finished Project?";
$title9="Delivery Date";
$title10="Price";
$title11="number of Bedrooms";
$title12="number of Bathrooms";
$title13="Pool available?";
$title14="Featured";
$title15="Upload Image (jpg,png,gif)";


$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
?>

<div class="grid_4">
        <div class="left-1">
            <h2 class="top-1 p3">Find a property</h2>
            <form id="form-1" class="form-1 bot-1" action="prop_result.php">
                <div class="select-1">
                    <label>Select Area</label>
                    <select name="field4" id="field4" >
    <?php



    $qry2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table4", $con);
if(!$qry2)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}



    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
    {
echo "<option value='".$row[$col4]."'>".$row[$col4]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
                    </select>   
                </div>
                <div class="select-1">
                    <label>Property type</label>
                    <select name="field7" id="field7">
    <?php



    $qry2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table7", $con);
if(!$qry2)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}



    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
    {
echo "<option value='".$row[$col7]."'>".$row[$col7]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
                    </select>   
                </div>
                          <div class="select-1">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input name="field10" type="text" id="field10" value="Type in Price" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Type in Price'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Address, City, Zip' ) this.value=''"  />
                </div>

                <div class="select-2">
                    <label>Beds</label>
                    <select name="field11" id="field11" >
                       <?php
 for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="select-2 last">
                    <label>Baths</label>
                    <select name="field12" id="field12">
                        <?php
 for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
                </div> 
                <a onClick="document.getElementById('form-1').submit()" class="button">Search</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
```

prop_result.php

```
<?php


//$field=$_POST['field'];
//$field2=$_POST['field2'];
//$field3=$_POST['field3'];
$field4=$_POST['field4'];
//$field5=$_POST['field5'];
//$field6=$_POST['field6'];
//$field7=$_POST['field7'];
$field8=$_POST['field8'];
//$field9=$_POST['date'];
$field10=$_POST['field10'];
$field11=$_POST['field11'];
$field12=$_POST['field12'];
//$field13=$_POST['field13'];
//$field14=$_POST['field14'];
//$field17=$_POST['field17'];


$qry_main=mysql_query("SELECT a.id, name, description, b.developer as pdev, c.agent as pagent ,g.country as pcountry,f.city as pcity,city_id, d.area as parea, size, furnished, h.type as ptype, finished, bed, bath, pool, featured from property a left join developer b on a.developer_id=b.id left join agent c on a.agent_id=c.id left join area d on a.area_id=d.id left join type h on a.type_id=h.id left join city f on d.city_id=f.id left join country g on f.country_id=g.id where a.area_id='$field4'",$con);
$qry_pic=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id'", $con);
$qry_pic1=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id' limit 1", $con);

if(!$qry_main)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}





while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_main))
{
echo "<h2 class='top-1 p3'>Other ".$row['ptype']." properties in ".$row['pcity']."</h2>";

}

/*
isset() is used to check wheather arctile id is received through url from "index.php" file and if it is set corresponding arctile is displayted using SELECT statement.
*/
echo "<div class='facts_container'>";

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT b.city_id as city_id,type_id FROM property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id WHERE a.id='$id'", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
                /* Fetching data from the field "title" */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
$city=$row['city_id'];
$type=$row['type_id'];

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT a.id,city_id, name, description, b.developer as pdev, c.agent as pagent ,g.country as pcountry,f.city as pcity, d.area as parea, size,price, furnished, h.type as ptype, finished, bed, bath, pool, featured from property a left join developer b on a.developer_id=b.id left join agent c on a.agent_id=c.id left join area d on a.area_id=d.id left join type h on a.type_id=h.id left join city f on d.city_id=f.id left join country g on f.country_id=g.id WHERE city_id='$city' AND type_id='$type' AND a.id!='$id' order by a.id DESC", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))

{
echo "<a href='showprop.php?id=".$row['id']."'><div class='related_prop'>";
echo "<span class='medtext'>".$row['name']." <br/>".$row['ptype']."<br />";
echo $row['bed']." Bed | ".$row['bath']." Bath<br /><span class='medbold'>".$row['price']."</span></span><br/>";

$id=$row['id'];

$qry_pic1=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id' limit 1", $con);

if(!$qry_pic1)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_pic1))
{
echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['aimage']."' /><br />";
}
echo "</div></a>";

}
}

?>

</div>
```

The error comes out saying the fields are undefined although I have named them in each case

Basically I need to tell prop_result.php that the form named form-1 has been submitted and go to work, but its refusing to even acknowledge that the fields that I have defined are existing. do i have to validate all fields with a `isset(_$post)` or can i some how set a statement that says if this form named form-1 submitted do this.`

ps: I know the code requires a lot of cleanup, for now I have commented out the fields I don't use at the moment and will add as necessary, but for now I just need to run the query and show results based on the form submitted.

Please let me know if you require any other information in order to assist me in my issue.

--------------update---------

new code after reading one of the answers. I've made a hidden input and using it as a isset_post . but now its coming blank with no error

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_post['form'])){

// $field4 = isset($_POST['field4']) ? $_POST['field4 '] : '';

//$field8 = isset($_POST['field8']) ? $_POST['field8'] : '';

//$field10 = isset($_POST['field10']) ? $_POST['field10'] : '';

//$field11 = isset($_POST['field11']) ? $_POST['field11'] : '';

//$field12 = isset($_POST['field12']) ? $_POST['field12'] : '';

//$field=$_POST['field'];
//$field2=$_POST['field2'];
//$field3=$_POST['field3'];
$field4=$_POST['field4'];
//$field5=$_POST['field5'];
//$field6=$_POST['field6'];
//$field7=$_POST['field7'];
//$field8=$_POST['field8'];
//$field9=$_POST['date'];
$field10=$_POST['field10'];
$field11=$_POST['field11'];
$field12=$_POST['field12'];
//$field13=$_POST['field13'];
//$field14=$_POST['field14'];
//$field17=$_POST['field17'];


$qry_main=mysql_query("SELECT a.id, name, description, b.developer as pdev, c.agent as pagent ,g.country as pcountry,f.city as pcity,city_id, d.area as parea, size, furnished, h.type as ptype, finished, bed, bath, pool, featured from property a left join developer b on a.developer_id=b.id left join agent c on a.agent_id=c.id left join area d on a.area_id=d.id left join type h on a.type_id=h.id left join city f on d.city_id=f.id left join country g on f.country_id=g.id where a.area_id='$field4'",$con);
$qry_pic=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id'", $con);
$qry_pic1=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id' limit 1", $con);

if(!$qry_main){
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_main)){
echo "<h2 class='top-1 p3'>Other ".$row['ptype']." properties in ".$row['pcity']."</h2>";


/*
isset() is used to check wheather arctile id is received through url from "index.php" file and if it is set corresponding arctile is displayted using SELECT statement.
*/
echo "<div class='facts_container'>";

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT b.city_id as city_id,type_id FROM property a left join area b on a.area_id=b.id WHERE a.id='$id'", $con);
if(!$qry){
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
                /* Fetching data from the field "title" */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
$city=$row['city_id'];
$type=$row['type_id'];

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT a.id,city_id, name, description, b.developer as pdev, c.agent as pagent ,g.country as pcountry,f.city as pcity, d.area as parea, size,price, furnished, h.type as ptype, finished, bed, bath, pool, featured from property a left join developer b on a.developer_id=b.id left join agent c on a.agent_id=c.id left join area d on a.area_id=d.id left join type h on a.type_id=h.id left join city f on d.city_id=f.id left join country g on f.country_id=g.id WHERE city_id='$city' AND type_id='$type' AND a.id!='$id' order by a.id DESC", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
echo "<a href='showprop.php?id=".$row['id']."'><div class='related_prop'>";
echo "<span class='medtext'>".$row['name']." <br/>".$row['ptype']."<br />";
echo $row['bed']." Bed | ".$row['bath']." Bath<br /><span class='medbold'>".$row['price']."</span></span><br/>";

$id=$row['id'];

$qry_pic1=mysql_query("SELECT a.image as aimage,a.property_id,b.id from images a right join property b on b.id=a.property_id where b.id='$id' limit 1", $con);

if(!$qry_pic1){
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_pic1)){
echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['aimage']."' /><br />";
}
echo "</div></a>";
}   
}
}
}

?>

</div>
```

Comment: What fields are undefined?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: field4 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\prop_result.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: field8 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\prop_result.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: field10 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\prop_result.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: field11 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\prop_result.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: field12 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\prop_result.php on line 17

Comment: You really shouldn't build modern PHP applications like this. Blending all of your database calls, PHP and HTML together is just bad design. I would reconsider your entire approach to this problem or you're going to be chasing your tail forever trying to make this thing work correctly.

Comment: thank @gnarly. please send an example of the right way so i can use that.

Comment: I can't really provide an example, I would look at Twig templates or leveraging a proper framework such as Symfony. Symfony uses Twig as the template engine. There's a bit of a learning curve to get going with Symfony, but in the end, you'll have a really nice application that cleanly separates your business logic, data model and presentation. Check out Symfony or any of the other frameworks out there. Makes life so, so much easier. They get you out of nitty gritty stuff and thinking more high level.

Comment: @gnarly. i want to design the code myself because then i can easily troubleshoot and modify it to my needs and reuse the code in multiple projects. i've had horrible experience in editing other people's code or trying to find workarounds to the limitations of some of these frameworks.

Comment: It's up to you my friend, but having done this sort of work for nearly 20 years, your plan requires a heavy lift on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple forms on your PHP, you must have an element or something (say a hidden div or an input element) that carries information about which form was submitted. Set it to 1 or the form name before you submit the page.

You could also check an isset-POST on the form id so that if the form was submitted it would be set to true. If the form was submitted, check for other fields.

Edit : I notice in your updated code that the reference to the form element does not include the POST method. In fact, no where in your html there is a reference to POST. You must mention whether the form should be submitted as GET or POST.

Change :

```
<form id="form-1" class="form-1 bot-1" action="prop_result.php">
```

To  :

```
<form id="form-1" class="form-1 bot-1" method = "POST" action="prop_result.php">
```

Comment: i like this approach, but for some reason, without any errors, my page is blank. question updated with new code

Comment: thank you whirl wind, i also figured that out and kicked myself for it...if you hadn't mentioned it i would have answered this question myself.